# Does Ryo ever kill anyone in the Shenmue games?

Tags: shenmue-2, shenmue

I'm doing some research for a game project involving game violence, and I can't remember if Ryo Hazuki ever killed anyone in the Shenmue games. He certainly swears to avenge his father, and he beats up a lot of people, but did he ever actually kill anyone? I can't remember. My gut tells me "no", but I can't say for certain.

Does anybody know for sure if Ryo's ever killed anybody?